# Cloud AutoML API has not been used in project 618104708054 before or it is disabled

Tags: automl, google-cloud-automl

I am trying to build a .NET small app to predict images using my model that was trianed on AutoML.

But I am getting this error:

> Cloud AutoML API has not been used in project 618104708054 before or
>   it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/automl.googleapis.com/overview?project=618104708054
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry

First - this is not the project I am using.
Second - If I go to the link with my real project id - it says to me that the api is working well.

My code look like these:

```
public static string SendPOST(string url, string json)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer GOOGLE_CLOUD_TOKEN");
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                //var res = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Response>(result);
                //return res;
                return result;
            }           
        }
```

I will appriciate your help,
Thanks.

Comment: I have been struggling with the same error all day. Unfortunately I've not solved it.

Comment: Hi, I left an answer down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally succeded to make it, the only issue is that I needed to create a service account using the web console:

[https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?supportedpurview=project&project=&folder=&organizationId=](http://I%20finally%20succeded%20to%20make%20it,%20the%20only%20issue%20is%20that%20I%20needed%20to%20create%20a%20service%20account%20%20using%20the%20web%20console%20(https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?supportedpurview=project&project=&folder=&organizationId=))

And then to download the json key and push it via the gcloud command from my PC -

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="[/PATH/TO/KEY/FILE.json]
```

I found the solution in this post:
["(403) Forbidden" when trying to send an image to my custom AutoML model via the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805268/403-forbidden-when-trying-to-send-an-image-to-my-custom-automl-model-via-the)